# insert Arabic values to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I can't insert Arabic language to Mysql database using the below code. When I check the values using phpMyAdmin, the field would be empty. Why is that so?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('عماد')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Copy the query to PhpMyAdmin SQL editor and see what error you'are getting

Comment: if your table is actually named `table` then that's a reserved word and will cause an error unless you put backticks around it.

Comment: Could you share with us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <your-table-name>`?

Comment: Just so you know, `mysql_query` has been deprecated for a while now.  You should probably look into mysqli or PDO.  Both support parameterized statements, and would make support for UTF-8 data easier and less error-prone.

Comment: gooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood i solved it <<<<<< but i do not know the reason !! >> i was coding on Zend studio , i had copied the code of page then new php page with Dreamwaver and past the code in it , then solved why ? what happened? please any one see tome why !!!!!????

Answer (score 1):

`name` field should be utf8
in the same time use this query directly after connecting to mysql, before executing any other query like the insert statement in your example

`set names 'utf8'`

then check phpmyadmin output, it should be correct

Comment: @EmadeldeenAbd-AllahAbdel-Hal: Is your script in UTF-8 as well?  Or are you using some Arabic code page?

Comment: Well, if your script is in an Arabic encoding, then MySQL will get mixed up about what characters you're sending.  UTF-8 only works *if you send UTF-8 encoded chars*.  You'll need to `SET NAMES` to the encoding used by the text, or encode the text as UTF-8 somehow.

Comment: gooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood i solved it <<<<<< but i do not know the reason !! >> i was coding on Zend studio , i had copied the code of page then new php page with Dreamwaver and past the code in it , then solved why ? what happened? please any one see tome why !!!!!????

Comment: @EmadeldeenAbd-AllahAbdel-Hal: If i had to guess, i'd say Zend was using your platform's default encoding, and DW used UTF-8.  But without having access to your machine, i couldn't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line .... u can insert special charecters.

```
    mysql_real_escape_string($query);
```

Comment: gooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood i solved it <<<<<< but i do not know the reason !! >> i was coding on Zend studio , i had copied the code of page then new php page with Dreamwaver and past the code in it , then solved why ? what happened? please any one see tome why !!!!!????

Answer (score 0):

```
  /** 
   * ALTER TABLE `myTable` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
   *  
   * There’s a generic way of doing by simply executing the MySQL query: 
   * SET NAMES utf8; 
   *  
   * ...and depending on which client/driver you’re using 
   * there are helper functions to do this more easily instead: 
   */ 

  // With the built in mysql functions 
  mysql_set_charset('utf8');  

  // With MySQLi 
  $mysqli->set_charset("utf8") 

  // With PDO_MySQL (as you connect) 
  $pdo = new PDO( 
      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 
      'username', 
      'password', 
      array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") 
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the field's `name` `collation` is set to: `'utf8_unicode_ci'` in PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Goto you database and change your field's `Collation` value to  `utf8_unicode_ci` .Thanks me later

for Java tuts visit: [Introduction to Java](http://onlineprogramminghub.com/java/)